# Entity Framework SaveChanges dropping values

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I have a situation where I am losing a dropdown value when calling SaveChanges in Entity Framework. If I have changed the value of the dropdown before I save, the value is preserved. If I don't change the value, it is converted to Nothing after the SaveChanges. This does not occur throughout my app, but it does happen with a hidden field and date field in another controller.

While debugging I can see that the value of the dropdown is present until the SaveChanges is called, so I'm completely baffled why it's gone afterwards.

If it would help to include other code, please let me know.

**Edit:** Just to point out, I'm using Oracle 11g, MVC 4, Entity Framework 5.

Here is the Save method that calls SaveChanges:

```
  Private Function Save(EEOComplaint As EEOComplaintViewModel) As ActionResult
        Dim objEEOComplaint As STAFF_ACTION

        If EEOComplaint.STAFF_ACTION_ID = 0 Then
            objEEOComplaint = Mapper.Map(Of EEOComplaintViewModel, STAFF_ACTION)(EEOComplaint)
        Else
            Dim objExistingSeparation As STAFF_ACTION = db.STAFF_ACTION.Find(EEOComplaint.STAFF_ACTION_ID)
            objEEOComplaint = Mapper.Map(Of EEOComplaintViewModel, STAFF_ACTION)(EEOComplaint, objExistingSeparation)
        End If

        ValidateForm(ModelState, objEEOComplaint)

        If ModelState.IsValid Then

            'setting these to Nothing because the mapper is setting
            'them to "VPM.EEOComplaintViewModel" for some reason
            If objEEOComplaint.POSITN_ACTN_TYPE = "VPM.EEOComplaintViewModel" Then objEEOComplaint.POSITN_ACTN_TYPE = Nothing
            If objEEOComplaint.HIRG_REQST_APPRVL_TYPE = "VPM.EEOComplaintViewModel" Then objEEOComplaint.HIRG_REQST_APPRVL_TYPE = Nothing
            If objEEOComplaint.RECRTMNT_TYPE = "VPM.EEOComplaintViewModel" Then objEEOComplaint.RECRTMNT_TYPE = Nothing
            If objEEOComplaint.AWARD_TYPE = "VPM.EEOComplaintViewModel" Then objEEOComplaint.AWARD_TYPE = Nothing

            If EEOComplaint.ARCHIVE_IND = "Y" Then objEEOComplaint.END_DT = Now.ToShortDateString

            If EEOComplaint.STAFF_ACTION_ID = 0 Then
                objEEOComplaint.CREATED_BY = Session("AppUserID")
                db.STAFF_ACTION.Add(objEEOComplaint)
            Else
                objEEOComplaint.UPDATED_BY = Session("AppUserID")
                UpdateModel(objEEOComplaint)
            End If

            db.SaveChanges()

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If

        EEOComplaint = Mapper.Map(Of STAFF_ACTION, EEOComplaintViewModel)(objEEOComplaint)
        EEOComplaint = GetViewModel(EEOComplaint)
        If EEOComplaint.STAFF_ACTION_ID = 0 Then EEOComplaint.ARCHIVE_IND = "N"
        GetDropdownData(EEOComplaint)
        Return View(EEOComplaint)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your controller code?

It looks like you entity is not tracked (correctly). In debug mode, what is the value of yourcontext.Entry(yourentity).State?

Check to make sure that you don't have set the EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID setter to internal. Don't do it like this: int EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID {get; internal set;}

It should be: int EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID {get; set;}

Comment: That Save function is really the only pertinent code in the controller, except that db is created in the class, outside of all other methods (class level variable). Were you looking for something specific?
db.Entry(objEEOComplaint).State = Modified which seems fine because I can update other values in the form even while that one dropdown value gets dropped.

Comment: If the entity state of objEEOComplaint == EntityState.Modified just before db.SaveChanges() and objEEOComplaint has the correct values it really should save all values. Are you really really sure that the values from the dropdownbox are correctly in objEEOComplaint just before db.SaveChanges()? You could check the generated SQL statement to see what is going on.

Comment: I can't edit to add images so here is the BEFORE: http://imgur.com/0W5sqCb and AFTER: http://imgur.com/cfSkYfI
You can see that the highlighted property changes from 6 to Nothing.

Comment: Can it be that you have the EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID setter set to internal? Like this: int EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID {get; internal set;}

Comment: The STAFF_ACTION class was auto-generated when I set up the datasource through entity framework. The property is set as Public Property EEO_COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID As Nullable(Of Integer)

Comment: There must be something we overlook, probably because we take it for granted. Can you show me your dbcontext and EEOComplaintViewModel class? Can you tell me more about the Datetime field and the hidden field with the same issue? I'm intrigued by this issue, because it really should work.

Comment: Richard, I finally figured out the issue. Turns out it was AutoMapper which I wasn't suspecting at all. I reverted to an older version and the problem disappeared. I still don't understand how this would be a problem, but I will contact the developer and let them know the issue I was experiencing. I truly appreciate your diligence, thank you!